# Typo in spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold ...?

Tags: apache-spark

Presumably I could have found a typo in *Spark version 3.1.1*. I am
using *Scala version 2.12.10* (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.11)

```
scala> spark.conf.get("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold")

res0: String = 10485760b
```

But should possibly be: 104857600.

Therefore:

```
scala> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", 104857600)
```

When you deploy with "10485760b", Spark cannot detect that one of the joined DataFrames is small (10 MB by default). The threshold for automatic broadcast join detection could be disabled. I hope my comment helps someone?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a typo but the correct value.

According to the documentation on Spark configuration, `autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` has a default value of 10MB and is defined as

> "Configures the maximum size in **bytes** for a table that will be broadcast to all worker nodes when performing a join."

Your proposed value of `104857600` would result in `104857600 / 1024 / 1024 = 100MB` which can potentially cause harm to the health of the applications performance.

In addition, at the [beginning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-properties) of the documentation it explains what the "b" stand for:

[image]

Comment: Wonder why they don't follow the standard practice of `b = bit` and `B = byte` hence causing confusion